# Construct a line through a given point with the normal vector $\boldsymbol u$

Tags: linear-algebra

The given point is $(1,2)$ and I have to use the toolbar from Geogebra in order to solve, I have researched the question but all the answers are for 3D space

I must use this app to make the line:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the perpendicular tool, third from the right.